# How do I disable multiple desktops on Windows Professional?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have a couple Windows Server 2003 machines that [autologin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) when they boot.  Unfortunately, these machines are locked in the closet where the IT department put them, and getting to the desktop that is provided by the autologin is something of a problem.  Every remote desktop connection gets its own desktop, so I don't get to see the one that is active in the closet.

How do I configure these boxes so they will not allow more than one desktop and will always connect remote desktop to the same one?  There aren't any options for this under My Computer/properties/remote.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with via RDP with the `/admin` option?  You could always just install VNC, and you will definitely get the console.

Comment: Windows XP Professional 2003... Never heard of it. Windows XP only allows one remote connection. Windows Server 2003 is another matter. Which do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run mstsc /console when connecting, that should work around the issue (while not preventing an rdp session without the console switch).

Comment: Or the /admin switch, depending on the version of the RDP client.

Comment: mstsc /console /admin was the required mantra to get to the home console.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP Professional is allowed only 1 remote connection. Unless if you are referring to Windows 2003 Server which is by default it's only 2 connections.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your IT department.